# RubyVersionMismatch when creating new Elastic Beanstalk worker environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, bundler, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

First time caller, long time listener. I have a rails app running without issue in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk web server environment, and I now want to deploy a similar app to a worker environment to do some async processing of uploaded files. For now, just to get it going, I am deploying the same version of my app (in other words, a version that runs fine in multiple web server environments) to the worker environment (which uses the identical platform as the web server environment), but am getting a RubyVersionMismatch when it tries to do the initial `rake assets:precompile`:

```
$ tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-activity.log

  + RAKE_TASK=assets:precompile
  + . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/use-app-ruby.sh
  ++ . /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
  +++ CHRUBY_VERSION=0.3.8
  +++ RUBIES=()
  +++ for dir in '"$PREFIX/opt/rubies"' '"$HOME/.rubies"'
  +++ [[ -d /opt/rubies ]]
  ++++ ls -A /opt/rubies
  +++ [[ -n ruby-1.9.3-p551
  ruby-2.0.0-p598
  ruby-2.1.5
  ruby-2.2.2
  ruby-current ]]
  +++ RUBIES+=("$dir"/*)
  +++ for dir in '"$PREFIX/opt/rubies"' '"$HOME/.rubies"'
  +++ [[ -d /.rubies ]]
  +++ unset dir
  +++ cat /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.ruby_version
  ++ chruby 2.2.2
  ++ case "$1" in
  ++ local dir match
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551
  ++ [[ ruby-1.9.3-p551 == *\2\.\2\.\2* ]]
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598
  ++ [[ ruby-2.0.0-p598 == *\2\.\2\.\2* ]]
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.5
  ++ [[ ruby-2.1.5 == *\2\.\2\.\2* ]]
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2
  ++ [[ ruby-2.2.2 == *\2\.\2\.\2* ]]
  ++ match=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-current
  ++ [[ ruby-current == *\2\.\2\.\2* ]]
  ++ [[ -z /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2 ]]
  ++ shift
  ++ chruby_use /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2 ''
  ++ [[ ! -x /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby ]]
  ++ [[ -n '' ]]
  ++ export RUBY_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2
  ++ RUBY_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2
  ++ export RUBYOPT=
  ++ RUBYOPT=
  ++ export PATH=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
  ++ PATH=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
  +++ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -
  ++ eval 'export RUBY_ENGINE=ruby;
  export RUBY_VERSION=2.2.2;
  export GEM_ROOT="/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0";'
  +++ export RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
  +++ RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
  +++ export RUBY_VERSION=2.2.2
  +++ RUBY_VERSION=2.2.2
  +++ export GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  +++ GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  ++ ((  0 != 0  ))
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-rake-task.rb assets:precompile' webapp
  + '[' false == true ']'
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' webapp
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:379:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.1.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `setup'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2016-03-04T15:28:08.146Z] INFO  [1693]  - [CMD-Startup/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/11_asset_compilation.sh] : Activity failed.
[2016-03-04T15:28:08.147Z] INFO  [1693]  - [CMD-Startup/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2016-03-04T15:28:08.147Z] INFO  [1693]  - [CMD-Startup/StartupStage0] : Activity failed.
[2016-03-04T15:28:08.147Z] INFO  [1693]  - [CMD-Startup] : Completed activity. Result:
  Command CMD-Startup failed.
```

My Gemfile does in fact call for v2.2.2, but if you notice, the bottom two lines of the stack trace show that the ruby that is being invoked lives in /opt/elasticbeanstalk, despite the fact that chruby is correctly finding and selecting version 2.2.2 from /opt/rubies/ruby-current. Any ideas why this is happening? What's the point of dynamically selecting a ruby version based on the containerconfig if EB is going to randomly fall back to its own local version?

Comment: Did you try adding a `.ruby-version` file in the root of your rails project?  It only needs to contain the version of Ruby in which you choose to use for that particular rails project.

Comment: I do have one, set to 2.2.2, but think that only helps for rvm and rbenv, and EB uses chruby

Comment: weird. do you run any custom config files or special ami?

Comment: Stock AMI. I have an .ebextensions file to install specific versions of rake and rack (`gem install -i /opt/rubies/ruby-current/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 rack -v 1.6.4`, `gem install -i /opt/rubies/ruby-current/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 rake -v 10.5.0`), but wouldn't think that would affect it.

Comment: How'd you go with this?

I'm currently hitting the same issue.

Comment: Haven't figured it out yet, been working on other things. Posted a question in the AWS forums to see if someone from Amazon can weigh in.  So far no response. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=226968

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if you're open to moving platforms, but have you considered using docker? (https://www.docker.com)

Comment: We've considered it, and will probably go that way at some point in the future, but don't really have time to do it now.